# How to use telescope with moloquent / mongodb?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, telescope, moloquent

Showing Error

> {message: "Call to a member function prepare() on null",…} exception:
>   "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError" file:
>   "/var/www/html/broc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php"
>   line: 326 message: "Call to a member function prepare() on null"
>   trace: [,…]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to debug that you are using correct DB.

FIle:

```
vendor/laravel/telescope/src/Http/Controllers/EntryController.php
function : index()

dd($storage)  //show dump
```

Output should be :

> DatabaseEntriesRepository {#1671   **#connection: "mongodb"**
>   #monitoredTags: null }

After that

You need to extend `EntryModel` which is in the
`vendor/laravel/telescope/src/Storage/DatabaseEntriesRepository.php`

location of the telescope package and set moloquent connection there.

now should be use **Moloquent** instead of **Eloquent** used like that

```
//use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use Moloquent as Model;

class EntryModel extends Model
```

For more detail follow below link

```
https://thewebtier.com/php/complete-guide-for-implementing-laravel-telescope-with-mongodb/
```

Answer (score 0):

A year now from the question date, with Laravel 6, the chosen answer will not suffice.

2 steps are needed to solve the issue:

1- as @Yuvraj mentioned change the extended model in `Laravel\Telescope\Storage\EntryModel`:

```
//use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use Moloquent as Model;

class EntryModel extends Model
```

2- in the same class is a function that scopes the query by the oprtions sent in the request:

```
    public function scopeWithTelescopeOptions($query, $type, EntryQueryOptions $options)
    {
        $this->whereType($query, $type)
                ->whereBatchId($query, $options)
                ->whereTag($query, $options)
                ->whereFamilyHash($query, $options)
                ->whereBeforeSequence($query, $options)
                ->filter($query, $options);

        return $query;
    }
```

the `filter` function checks if the record has the property `should_display_on_index` set to true, which is set as default in the migration:
`$table->boolean('should_display_on_index')->default(true);`
But since a mongoDB is used, the default paramater is not respected and hence, is not added to the record.

To resolve this you have two options:

a) comment out the call to filter in the previously mentioned function:

```
    public function scopeWithTelescopeOptions($query, $type, EntryQueryOptions $options)
    {
        $this->whereType($query, $type)
                ->whereBatchId($query, $options)
                ->whereTag($query, $options)
                ->whereFamilyHash($query, $options)
                ->whereBeforeSequence($query, $options)
                /*->filter($query, $options)*/;

        return $query;
    }
```

However, if you are going to use the filter later by setting the `should_display_on_index` to false, you'll need to modify the filter function instead:

```
 protected function filter($query, EntryQueryOptions $options)
    {
        if ($options->familyHash || $options->tag || $options->batchId) {
            return $this;
        }

        // $query->where('should_display_on_index', true);
        $query->where('should_display_on_index', '!=', false);

        return $this;
    }
```